# I installed pygame on linux using pip,but when trying to import it in VS Code it says no module named "pygame".How do I fix that?

Tags: linux, module, pip, pygame, installation

I am using Ubuntu. I installed pip and after that installed pygame.I tried to import the module but I keep getting this error: no module named "pygame".

Comment: Please show the framgents of code you tried  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind,found the solution.You need to specify the version of python,because ubuntu has already got python 2.7,so it will add the module to python 2.7.

> python3.7 -m pip install modulename
>     (or what your version is)

Comment: Yep.  You can also say `pip3 install pygame`, which will install for python 3.x